# How to access constants in models.py, from django template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have about 10 constants that I want to display on my website. These constants are specified in models.py.

How do I use these constants in my Django template?

I'm using class-based views.

```
class PanelView(RequireBuyerOrSellerMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "core/panel.html"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should import them in view.py, then in your view function, pass them in the context to feed the template.

models.py

```
CONSTANT1 = 1
CONSTANT2 = 2
```

view.py

```
from app.models import CONSTANCT1, CONSTANCE2

def func(request):
    context['constant1'] = CONSTANT1
    context['constant2'] = CONSTANT2
    # return HttpResponse()
```

template.html

```
{{ constant1 }}
{{ constant2 }}
```

**Edit:**

Class based views has no difference than function based views. According to [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context), override `get_context_data` to add extra stuff to context.

Comment: Thanks I'm using class-based views

Comment: Minor discrepancy in name of constant imported and constant variable declared ;)

Answer (score 3):

Usually you should go the way @Shang Wang suggested, but if you want to use the constants in many templates it might be worth to write a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags)

```
from django import template
from app import models

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_constants(name):
    return getattr(models, name, None)
```

And in your template:

```
{% get_constants 'CONSTANT1' %}
```

Comment: Can I access it if it's a dictionary?

Comment: In django1.9 you can save it in a template variable and then access the values of the dict.